# Command Line Varaible is not overriding Suite Level Variable in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

As per Robot Documentation

> Variables set in the command line have the highest priority of all
>   variables that can be set before the actual test execution starts.
>   They override possible variables created in Variable tables in test
>   case files, as well as in resource and variable files imported in the
>   test data

I have defined suite level variable `browser` in Keyword A and calling that keyword in Suite Setup

```
Log Browser is ${browser}   console=True
Set Suite Variable  ${browser}  chrome
Log Browser is ${browser}   console=True
```

And Also Passing the same variable using command line --variable 
`pybot.bat --variable browser:ie` 
but from logs it looks like Suite Variable is overriding the command line variable.

**What am I missing?**
`
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you quoted says it all (I've added emphasis):

> Variables set in the command line have the highest priority of all variables that can be set **before the actual test execution starts**

Once the test starts, keywords can override the values set by the variable table and command line arguments.