# How to set dependent global variables in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a resources file containing a global variable which is dependent on another global variable.

```
${VAR1}    ${EMPTY}
${VAR2}    some_value/${VAR1}.json
```

In my testcase I set the value for `${VAR1}` using the `set global variable` keyword

```
set global variable  ${VAR1}  foo
log  ${VAR1}
log  ${VAR2}
```

I am expecting that the update to `${VAR1}` in turn updates `${VAR2}` as well so the output should be:

```
foo
some_value/foo.json
```

and not

```
foo
some_value/${EMPTY}.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${Var2} is passed from command line , which has the highest priority.
In order to override it , you need to define ${var2} in your Keyword file again, as you did for ${var1}

Example

```
set Suite variable  ${VAR1}  foo
set Suite variable  ${VAR2}  some_value/${VAR1}.json
```

You can also refer this answer

[Command Line Varaible is not overriding Suite Level Variable in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900886/command-line-varaible-is-not-overriding-suite-level-variable-in-robot-framework)

Comment: ```${VAR2}``` is already defined in my resource file as a Global variable. I am not passing it from the command line. I want it to be dynamically set based on the value set to ```${VAR1}``` using the ```set global variable``` keyword.

Comment: @Sid When you assign a value to a variable it will have the value (not a reference to VAR1), i.e. VAR2 won't have any understanding of VAR1 once initially set. If you want VAR2 to update then answer above is correct

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to assign anything to ${VAR1}

just declare ${VAR1} with no value inside variables section.
e.g

```
*** variables ***
${VAR1}    
${VAR2}    some_value/${VAR1}.json
```

Comment: This does not work. The output in this case would be:
```
foo
some_value/.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In the test suite you need to declare the VAR2 as a global variable. Once VAR2 declared in the test suite the value of VAR2 will be updated everytime the VAR1 is updated.

```
Sample Test
    log to console  ${VAR1}
    log to console  ${VAR2}
    set global variable  ${VAR1}  foo
    ${VAR2}=  set variable  test/ ${VAR1}
    set global variable  ${VAR2}
    log to console   ${VAR1}
    log to console   ${VAR2}
    set global variable  ${VAR1}  foo2
```

Value of VAR2 will be now test/ foo2

```
log to console   ${VAR1}
log to console   ${VAR2}
```